# like clause in JPA native sql query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpa, where-clause, sql-like

I have a query that returns a list of products:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from Product join Product_Pro pp on Product.ID = pp.PRODUCT_ID where A_ID= ?1 order by name",
        nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findAll(long id);
```

How do I add a `LIKE` clause to this?

When I execute this statement in my DB a get a result:

```
Select * from Product join Product_Pro pp on Product.ID = pp.PRODUCT_ID where A_ID= ?1 AND name LIKE '%someString%' AND content LIKE '%someString%' order by name
```

but how do I add `LIKE` to my JPA native query?

I have tried:

```
@Query(value = "Select * from Product join Product_Pro pp on Product.ID = pp.PRODUCT_ID where A_ID= ?1 and name LIKE '%?%' order by name",
            nativeQuery = true)
        List<Product> findAll(long id, String name);
```

and

```
@Query(value = "Select * from Product join Product_Pro pp on Product.ID = pp.PRODUCT_ID where A_ID= ?1 and name LIKE '%:name%' order by name",
            nativeQuery = true)
        List<Product> findAll(long id,@Param("name") String name);
```

But none of these work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that you want `CONCAT()`:

```
and name LIKE CONCAT('%', ?2, '%')
```

Comment: For those using Oracle,  CONCAT(CONCAT('%', :param), '%')   or  CONCAT(CONCAT('%', ?n), '%')  with ordered arguments.  The Oracle implementation accepts only two parameters.

Comment: I was doubting my sanity already! hahaahhahaa thanks! <3